# What ControlCategory should I use for my android Chromecast app game?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm making a game that runs on the Chromecast. I'm stuck where I have to build a MediaRouteSelector. I'm not sure what control category I should use. When I use the code in the examples, the cast button doesn't show up (I do put the real application ID I got from the Dev Console):

```
  mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()  
        .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"))  
        .build();
```

The Chromecast icon shows up when I change the code to this, though:

```
 mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()  
        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)  
        .build();
```

There are two other categories I could use though, and I want to make sure I'm choosing the correct one.

```
MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO  
MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are building a game, you'd need to write a custom receiver and you'd need to register on the cast dev console to get an application id. That is the ID that should be put in for the "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID". If by doing that you do not see your chromecast, then it means you have not correctly done the registration steps for your device; serial number might have been entered incorrectly or the checkbox to send the serial number to Google may not have been checked.